# im upgrading from 11.04 to 13.04

Tags: system-installation

How to do a full install of the 13.04 onto my pc . I am presently on 11.04 version, & I'm downloading the 13.04 version iso file but how do i do a clean install.
regards

Beck

Comment: **Backup all your user files. Really, after you to a clean install, you will have wiped everything.**

Otherwise, click on karel's link.

Comment: Even if you do try to upgrade instead a clean install **Backup all your user files** things can go wrong.  I'd recommend a clean install - you get a cleaner system that way

Answer (score 0):

Use the pre installed disk burner that came with your copy of ubuntu 11.04 ..burn the Ubuntu 13.04 image to a D.V.D.-R or D.V.D.-RW once that is finished remove the disk and shut your system down..when your system comes back on press the deleat key rapidly your system will boot to somthing called bios poke around in the bios till you fine a spot named boot priority ...once in this section set the boot priority of your disk drive first and your hard drive second ..once this is done save exit and once again shut down your computer...turn it back on and quickly open the disk tray and insert your D.V.D. of the Ubuntu 13.04 O.S. ...if it starts booting into Ubuntu befor you can get the disk in it is perfectly okay ..just hold the power buttion down till the system shuts off ...if it does turn it back on...if you made it in time your screen will say "booting from C.D." or "Booting from Disk" ...do not press anything just let the computer load "this should take between 5 and 30 mins" once it loads click install Ubuntu and follow the on screen instructions ...if you need more help please just ask